# Text not being put in same position through loop

Tags: swiftui

I have a loop that iterates through an array of day names, and creates a Text for each, which are then spread around a circle. The problem is that the text changes position with each iteration - appearing to get lower, then higher again. Below is the code I use:

```
struct LabelPositionTest: View {

private var sectorAngle: Double = Double(360/7)
private var dayNameArray: Array<String> = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
private var viewWidth: CGFloat = 180
private var viewHeight: CGFloat = 100

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader
    {   selectorWheelGeometry in
            ForEach((0...6), id: \.self) {i in
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing)
            {
                if dayNameArray.count > i
                {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text(dayNameArray[i])
                        .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(90))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: selectorWheelGeometry.size.width/2.25, height: viewHeight)
            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double((i-1)*(360/7))+(90 + (0.5 * sectorAngle))), anchor: .leading)
            .position(x: selectorWheelGeometry.size.width/2 + (selectorWheelGeometry.size.width/2.25)/2, y: selectorWheelGeometry.size.height/2)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: Code has been changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with this kind of rotated view, I have found that the easiest way to fix errors is to create the base view first, and then position and rotate the base view as a unit. Often, I will create this unit as a separate view, but your example was simple enough that I just created the `Rectangle()` and overlayed the `Text()`. One other thing I did was to switch the dimensions on the `Rectangle()`. Essentially, you had a `Rectangle()` lying on its side, and then you rotated the text to try to match the `Rectangle()`. I stood the `Rectangle()` up and overlayed the text in a normal orientation with a top alignment and some `.padding()`.

The reason your labels weren't in the same place was that they were all rotated before positioning. If you show your code in preview, and then highlight the `Text()`, you will see the `Text()` view outlines are all different sizes. That accounts for the misplaced labels. The placement as per above, resolves this issue.

The commented code is below:

```
struct LabelPositionTest: View {
    
    private var sectorAngle: Double {
        Double(360/dayNameArray.count)
    }
    private var dayNameArray: Array<String> = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    private var viewWidth: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { selectorWheelGeometry in
            ZStack {
                // A much safer way of obtaining the index of an array in a ForEach is to zip the array
                // and its indices together, and then iterate off the array. This prevents out of bounds
                // errors, and, if the array elements are Identifiable, still allows you to use .move()
                // and .delete. The id: \.0 simply tells the ForEach to iterate on the first element in the zip
                ForEach(Array(zip(dayNameArray, dayNameArray.indices)), id: \.0) { day, index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .overlay(
                            Text(day)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(.top),
                            alignment: .top
                        )
                        .frame(width: viewWidth, height: selectorWheelGeometry.size.width/2.25)
                        // You already had sectorAngle defined, so I just used that. I also removed
                        // the extra 90 degree rotation. You can put that back in if you don't want a
                        // top start. This was just simplification for the answer.
                        .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double(index) * sectorAngle), anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I did notice that the text views were all different sizes… but wasn’t sure how to correct that!

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` constant range syntax for 7 days is:

```
ForEach(0..<7) { i in
```

Your constant vars should be lets.

Comment: That is true, Thank you! It doesn't change the layout of the views though.